# Override spring-boot application.properties with external properties

Tags: spring, spring-boot, application.properties

I have a spring-boot application.
I have 3 properties file:

1. a property file inside the spring-boot jar - *myjar.jar* called application.properties (**which is package inside the jar**)
2. a property file outside the jar, at the jar location under *configurations/global.properties*
3. a property file outside the jar, at the jar location under *configurations/java.properties*

The problem is, I'm running the following command:

```
java -Dlogging.config=logback.xml -jar "myjar.jar" spring.config.location=classpath:/application.properties,file:./configurations/global.properties,file:./configurations/java.properties
```

And I get an exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myApplication': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'Data.StoresDb.LakeConnectionString' in value "${Data.StoresDb.LakeConnectionString}"
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:405)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1422)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
        at org.springframework.beans.fa
```

in *myApplication.java,* I have:

```
@Value("${Data.StoresDb.LakeConnectionString}")
String dataLakeStoreDb;
```

and in my *application.properties* I **do not** have Data.StoresDb.LakeConnectionString, but I **do** have it in my global.properties, I would expect spring to resolve all files before trying to ser the value Data.StoresDb.LakeConnectionString

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You pass the arg/value as a raw Java argument :

```
java -jar "myjar.jar" spring.config.location=...
```

The argument will be present in the `String[] args` of the main class but the Spring environment will not be aware about that.
You have to prefix it with `--` to make the argument to be Spring environment aware :

```
java -jar "myjar.jar" --spring.config.location=...
```

From the [official documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.0.1.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-command-line-args) :

> By default SpringApplication will convert any command line option
>   arguments (starting with “--”, e.g. --server.port=9000) to a property
>   and add it to the Spring Environment

Or as alternative pass it as a system property :

```
java -Dspring.config.location=... -jar "myjar.jar"
```

As a side note : beware `spring.config.location` overrides the default locations while `spring.config.additional-location` introduced in Spring Boot 2 adds the specified locations to the default locations.